Hitting closed set for right-continuous process
It is known that the random variable $$\tau = \inf \lbrace t \ge 0 : X_t \in A \rbrace$$
is a stopping time with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_t^X\right)$ if $A$ is a closed set and $X_t$ is a continuous process.
Is it also true if we only assume right-continuity?
